# Not able to deactivate Alt+Shift for switching between sources. Need it for smart column selection in the text editor

Tags: keyboard, shortcuts

I have successfully updated Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. While updating I was asked to set a keyboard shortcut to switch between Latin (not sure something like this) and US keyboard layout and I was unfortunately stupid enough to set it to Alt+Shift.
Now I got problems because I would like to use this shortcut to start a smart column selection in the text editor (actually c++ programming). But anytime I press Shift+Alt the source language is switched instead.
The Settings->Keyboards Shortcuts->Typing->"Switch to next input source" are set to Super+Space (no Alt+Shift at al) Also tried to disable this issue. No effect.
This shortcut / setting seems to be hidden quite deep.

Many thanks for any good idea how to resolve it

Cheers

Comment: What is your desktop environment? GNOME, KDE, whatever? What is the output of `cat /etc/default/keyboard | grep XKBOPTIONS` .

Comment: The desktop environment is GNOME
The output of cat /etc/default/keyboard | grep XKBOPTIONS is
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp
I have already deleted grp:alt_shift_toggle string from there. No effect

Answer (score 1):

The options for toggling keyboard layout are those starting with `grp:` in [`man xkeyboard-config`](https://manpages.debian.org/buster/xkb-data/xkeyboard-config.7.en.html#OPTIONS).
You have chosen `grp:alt_shift_toggle` when configuring your system. To revert it to the defaults,
simply delete that string from `/etc/default/keyboard` via text-editor. It *may* also be possible
via `dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. which is an interactive tool, but I'm not sure if
it will ask about that option. Worth giving it a try.

Comment: Thank you. I have already done it. Here is the content of my /etc/default/keyboard

Comment: Sorry. I was too fast :) 
XKBLAYOUT="us"
XKBVARIANT=""
BACKSPACE="guess"
XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"

Comment: It does not help. The same behavior as before